# Unable to see count value in counter example using ngRx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Here is the code:

> state.ts

```
export interface AppState{
  count : number;
}
```

> actions.ts

```
export const INCREMENT: string = '[Counter] INCREMENT';
export class increment implements Action{
   readonly type = INCREMENT;
}

export const DECREMENT: string = '[Counter] DECREMENT';
export class decrement implements Action{
    readonly type = DECREMENT;
}

export type All
    = increment
    | decrement;
```

> reducer.ts

```
const initState: AppState = { count: 0 };

export function counterReducer(state: AppState = initState, action: Action)         {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
        return Object.assign({}, state, { count: state.count + 1 });
    case DECREMENT:
        return Object.assign({}, state, { count: state.count - 1 });
    default:
        return state;    
  }
}
```

> module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({counterReducer})
  ],
  providers : [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> my-component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Welcome to the Redux Counter example';
  counter$ : Observable<number>;
  constructor(public store : Store<AppState>,){
    this.counter$ = this.store.select('count'); // <-- This is not working
  }

  increase(){
    this.store.dispatch(new increment());
  }

  decrease(){
    this.store.dispatch(new decrement());
  }
}
```

I am not able to see `counter$` getting changed, although the reducers are getting called and the state getting changed. As my 1st ngRx project I know I am missing a very small concept while observing the `Store`.

can someone please help ?

Comment: Where abouts are you subscribing to `counter$`? Also, I think you need to change `StoreModule.forRoot({counterReducer})` to `StoreModule.forRoot({count: counterReducer})`

Comment: @user184994: Applying your suggestion made html `{{counter$ | async}}` as `[object Object]`. Not sure why async is not converting it.

Comment: I've added an answer below that should address that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change `StoreModule.forRoot({counterReducer})` to `StoreModule.forRoot({count: counterReducer})`

When you subscribe, bear in mind that this will return an object of type `AppState` like below:

```
{ count: 0 };
```

So when you're using async pipe, change it to:

```
{{ (counter$ | async)?.count }}
```

This will read from the object once it's been unwrapped. We add the `?` to ensure that we don't get any errors before the observable has been unwrapped

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. Will keep this in mind. :)

Comment: can you also please explain why we needed `count` for StoreModule. I saw `static forRoot<T, V extends Action = Action>(reducers: ActionReducerMap<T, V> | InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<T, V>>, config?: StoreConfig<T, V>): ModuleWithProviders;` in the source code and getting confused

Comment: That part of the setup is providing the keys and values to the store. The key is what's used in the `.select` function, so that the store knows which reducer to use, and therefore where to get the state. If we simply write `({counterReducer})`, the key is going to be the same as the variable name, i.e. `counterReducer`. If you want to be able to select using `count` as the key, you need to set the key as `count` by doing `{count: counterReducer}`

Comment: Thanks ! I made a mistake by casting State with AppState `constructor(public store : Store<AppState>)` in the component. hence I was forced to select `count`. I removed it `constructor(public store : Store<any>)`  and I was able to get store via keys. Many Thanks for your time.